# AppEngine Python - updating entity properties without twenty elif statements

Tags: python, djangoappengine

Suppose I have an AppEngine model defined with twenty different StringProperty properties.  And then I have a web form, which POSTs updated values for an entity of this model.  I end up with something like this after reading in the form data:

```
entity_key['name'] = 'new_name'
entity_key['city'] = 'new_city'
entity_key['state'] = 'new_state'
etc...
```

To actually assign these values to the entity, I'm presently doing something like this:

```
if property == 'name':
  entity.name = entity_key['name']
elif property == 'city':
  entity.city = entity_key['city']
elif property == 'state':
  entity.state = entity_key['state']
etc...
```

Is there any way to assign the property values without twenty elif statements?  I see that there is the model.properties() function, but I don't see anyway to tie all this together.

All help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The same effect as for your `if` / `elif` tree could be obtained by a single statement:

```
setattr(entity, property, entity_key[property])
```

This is just elementary Python, working the same way in every Python version since 1.5.2 (and perhaps earlier -- I wasn't using Python that many years ago!-), and has nothing specifically to do with App Engine, nor with Django, nor with the combination of the two.

Answer (score 0):

Cool.  Just for others' reference, the following two snippets are identical:

```
entity.some_property = "cat";

setattr(entity, "some_property", "cat")
```

I did know about the setattr function, Alex, so thanks for helping me out.